# Update this Custom Tile every Minute Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have got a Custom tile, an Image using xaml with different images for the different sizes.

How do I update this custom tile using Windows Phone 8.1 every minute? (I am currently running Windows Phone 8, so I assume that I will need to update this to 8.1?).

It's to display bus times on tile is this doable?

Code is how I create the Tile - How do I incorporate this in the Sample Clock Tile App that updates every minute?

```
 TileControl2LiveM frontTile4 = new TileControl2LiveM();
                 TileName = "";
                 TileName = BusNameWNaptan;
                 TileData tileData4 = new TileData()

                 {
                     Text1 = BusNameWNaptan,
                     Service1 = Service1,
                     Service2 = Service2,
                     Service3 = Service3,

                     Destination1 = Destination1,
                     Destination2 = Destination2,
                     Destination3 = Destination3,

                     Time1 = Time1,
                     Time2 = Time2,
                     Time3 = Time3,

                     Updated = "Last Updated: " + shorttime

                     // myDateTime.ToShortTimeString());
                 };

                 frontTile4.DataContext = tileData4;
                 frontTile4.Measure(new Size(173, 173));
                 frontTile4.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 173, 173));
                 var bmp4 = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
                 bmp4.Render(frontTile4, null);
                 bmp4.Invalidate();

                 var isf4 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                 var filename4 = "/Shared/ShellContent/med" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg";


            {
                     using (var stream4 = isf.OpenFile(filename4, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                     {
                         bmp4.SaveJpeg(stream4, 173, 173, 0, 100);
                     }


 var data4 = new FlipTileData
                     {
                         BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/med/" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute)
                     };
                 }

FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData()
                {
                    //Title = "[title]",
                    //BackTitle = "[back of Tile title]",
                    //BackContent = "[back of medium Tile size content]",
                    //WideBackContent = "[back of wide Tile size content]",
                    //Count = [count],
                    SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                    //BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative),
                    WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/wide" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                    WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/live" + BusNameWNaptan + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                };
```

Comment: Are you running this from within your app, or from a background process?

Comment: The process is within the app. I have tried to create a sample periodic one but now stopped. I don't know what's the best way. As this will need to update every minute. But can it then pause for a few hours an then start again?

Comment: [The ShellTileSchedule class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule(v=vs.105).aspx) allows for hourly updates, but doesn't need your app running, nor a background agent. The other option might be to use a background thread whilst your app is running.

Comment: On a tangent, have you considered the geofencing facilities (so, to take a hypothetical use case, "When user leaves work, look up the bus times/delays from the stop where they get on to go home")

Comment: Yes, I have just implemented on my test app a way a user selects the stops for home and work so before that time it changes the stop in the app to the stop. So when users open the app the next bus is showing their stop for home/work. But have not much an idea how this can be implemented.

Comment: There's [an example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn322031.aspx) about waking up a background task (to update your tile) based on a geofence event

Comment: Ok that could be useful for the home and work stops. For the normal stops, would a periodic task work? The idea would be they it will just update. Or they (the user) could set the threshold for the geofence event?

Comment: Depends on your use case - if you're having a tile for a "favourite stop", you *could* create a geofence for each tile, so that it updates when your end user gets close, in addition to a background schedule